# Prometheus always behaviour when queried for an instant vector

Tags: prometheus, promql

When querying Prometheus for

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance="localhost:9090"}
```

I see the browser makes a call where the current time is used in the query parameter **time**:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=process_cpu_seconds_total%7Binstance%3D%22localhost%3A9090%22%7D&time=1700078953.325' \
--compressed
```

And the result

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[{"metric":{"__name__":"process_cpu_seconds_total","instance":"localhost:9090","job":"prometheus"}," 
 value":[1700078953.325,"0.82"]}]}}%
```

ALWAYS matched the timestamp given as query parameter.

When I query for a range vector, the result is close to what I expect,
the browser still uses the current time as query param, but in the result
usually this time is not there as the metric is only scraped every 15 seconds.

```
curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=process_cpu_seconds_total%7Binstance%3D%22localhost%3A9090%22%7D%5B1m%5D&time=1700078953.325' \
  --compressed


{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[{"metric":{"__name__":"process_cpu_seconds_total","instance":"localhost:9090","job":"prometheus"}," 
 values":[[1700078900.426,"0.8"],[1700078915.427,"0.8"],[1700078930.388,"0.82"],[1700078945.388,"0.82"]]}]}}%
```

Why does prometheus always pretends to know the value of **now**, when we ask query for an instant vector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query for instant vector (directly or indirectly, like `sum(my_metric)` or `metric1 + metric2`) Prometheus simply returns newest sample before requested time. [This is mainly to support cases like aggregation (`sum`, `avg`, and so on), where multiple aggregated time series do not exactly align in time.](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness)

When you query range vector Prometheus returns values from within specified range as is. Since range vectors can only be used in limited cases (mainly aggregation/processing over time and rarely by simply requesting `my_metric[1m]`) it is reasonable to expect that none of those cases don't require any alignment for different time series, and thus no such mechanism is implemented.

Comment: But time series of a same metric are already aligned, as all share the same timestamps correct ? btw thanks for taking time to reply.

Comment: @GionJh, not necessary: if metrics are coming from different targets, for example.

Comment: Alright, I see now, thanks!